# Would snow shut down Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

How many inches/centimeters of snow would it take before Hogwarts throws the towel down and all the Houses get a free snow day or two hour delay where classes instead of starting at 9am, start at 11 and are shortened in length?

In fact, is the Scotland lowlands pretty weak at handling snowfall where things grind to a halt like London/Kent county, or are they more like the NE US such as Boston MA where they just keep on trucking until they can't put away the snow? Apparently it seems they can't even get a free "Basilisk Day" to happen as school was still open and can't get a Dementor Day either to do the job.

Comment: You know you're comparing an imaginary school to a real one right?

Comment: I doubt this is answerable and plus for all I know there's a "Snow clearioso!" spell that clears snow anyway...

Comment: Why would it? All of the towers and most of the classrooms all seem to be connected to the main castle. It looks like very few of the classes take place outside or out of the main structure.

Comment: To close voters - [we don't close questions just because there is no explicit/canon answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184), and if there is one, the answer would not be opinion based.

Comment: It's a boarding school, all of the students are already there, so a two-hour delay on starting lessons would be pointless (presumably the point of such a delay is to make it easier for students to travel to school safely). And, as phantom42 said, the majority of the castle is interconnected; they can reach almost all of their lessons without going outside. I *think* there's a precedent for Herbology being cancelled due to really severe weather during the winter from the books, but I'm not 100% on that.

Comment: We also see several spells used in the books to deal with snow. Hermione's enchanted fire from Philosopher's Stone (may also make a reappearance in later books, I'm not sure) to keep warm in cold weather, and a spell used specifically to melt snow used in one of the later books (I don't recall which), though it may have been as early as Chamber of Secrets. Hogwarts is on a mountain, if I recall, so hardly the Scottish lowlands. They also get snow every winter, so unlike London (which gets snow relatively infrequently) they'd be used to dealing with it.

Comment: @phantom42 it is not opinion based because there is no canon answer. It is opinion based every school district has different rules for how/when school are delayed or closed. Sometimes it is not even the total snow fall but the temperature, ice on roads, or other factors.

Comment: @Skooba yes, and the question is about ONE school. does *this* school have a policy? what is it? maybe it doesn't. the answer would be "no, there is no policy because there is no need." or maybe it does, "yes, they close if the temp drops below 0 or there is four feet of snow." see? no opinion.

Comment: One word to answer all of these Harry Potter "What if" questions: ***MAGIC***

Comment: So the students all live in the castle? Where do the warthogs, I mean Hogwarts,  professors and staff live?  I guess the house elves live in the basement.  Where do the other staff beings and the professors live, and can they use magic to get to the castle if they need to?

Comment: @phantom42, isn't the point that any possible answer about the existence and/or nature of said policy would be nothing but a wild guess, i.e., an opinion?  I don't have a strong opinion either way, but I'm not clear on what sort of question *would* be opinion-based if this one isn't.

Comment: @HarryJohnston [Informed speculative answers are fine](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3484/5184) if you can't find a canon one. If you just throw out a wild guess with nothing to back it up, it'll be treated as a  low quality answer. For here,  you might show that there are cases where magic is used to deal with inclement weather to explain that such a policy isn't necessary and that there probably isn't one. If we didn't allow speculative answers, we'd have to close all questions without an explicit canon answer, [which we don't do](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3014/5184).

Comment: @phantom42, good point; I'd somehow overlooked the fact that several of the upvoted comments provide perfectly adequate reasoning and could be turned into satisfactory answers.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: You should be more concerned if the great hall ceiling starts snowing.

Answer (score 7):

## Hogwarts did get a lot of snow at least once, and class continued.

Hogwarts had several feet of snow one year, and classes continued as usual. Some places in the castle were chilly, but students were still expected to attend their classes. This is logical - they wouldn’t need transportation to get to school since they live there, and since they’d be there and have to stay inside anyway, they might as well continue their classes. Since they’d be there anyway there’s no reason to cancel class.

> “One morning in mid-December, Hogwarts woke to find itself covered in several feet of snow. The lake froze solid and the Weasley twins were punished for bewitching several snowballs so that they followed Quirrell around, bouncing off the back of his turban. The few owls that managed to battle their way through the stormy sky to deliver post had to be nursed back to health by Hagrid before they could fly off again.
>
> No one could wait for the holidays to start. While the Gryffindor common room and the Great Hall had roaring fires, the draughty corridors had become icy and a bitter wind rattled the windows in the classrooms. Worst of all were Professor Snape’s classes down in the dungeons, where their breath rose in a mist before them and they kept as close as possible to their hot cauldrons.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 12 (The Mirror of Erised)*</sup></sub>

## Even their outdoor classes continued in the snow.

The two outdoor classes at Hogwarts, Herbology and Care of Magical Creatures, continued even in heavy snow.

> “Snow was still thick upon the grounds, and the greenhouse windows were covered in condensation so thick that they couldn’t see out of them in Herbology. Nobody was looking forward to Care of Magical Creatures much in this weather, though, as Ron said, the Skrewts would probably warm them up nicely, either by chasing them or by blasting off so forcefully that Hagrid’s cabin caught fire.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 24 (Rita Skeeter’s Scoop)*</sup></sub>

They were less comfortable, but they continued.

> “Hurry up, now, the bell rang five minutes ago,’ she barked at them, as they struggled towards her through the snow.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 24 (Rita Skeeter’s Scoop)*</sup></sub>

## There are spells to combat snow, but teachers rarely used them.

There are spells that would help with heavy snowfalls. Hermione used a charm to create hot air to clear snow with.

> “Ignore them, just ignore them,’ intoned Hermione, pulling out her wand and performing the charm to produce hot air again, so that she could melt them an easier path through the untouched snow between them and the greenhouses.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 21 (The Eye of the Snake)*</sup></sub>

When it was snowing heavily, though, the teachers and staff didn’t really use magical measures to either clear the snow or warm the castle.

> “October extinguished itself in a rush of howling winds and driving rain and November arrived, cold as frozen iron, with hard frosts every morning and icy draughts that bit at exposed hands and faces. The skies and the ceiling of the Great Hall turned a pale, pearly grey, the mountains around Hogwarts were snowcapped, and the temperature in the castle dropped so low that many students wore their thick protective dragonskin gloves in the corridors between lessons.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 19 (The Lion and the Serpent)*</sup></sub>

#### Herbology *was* once cancelled, but only indirectly due to snow.

Herbology was canceled when Professor Sprout was growing Mandrakes in the winter, to revive the Petrified victims of the basilisk. However, that was because she wanted to handle ensuring their protection herself since it was important.

> “By next morning, however, the snow that had begun in the night had turned into a blizzard so thick that the last Herbology lesson of term was cancelled: Professor Sprout wanted to fit socks and scarves on the Mandrakes, a tricky operation she would entrust to no one else, now that it was so important for the Mandrakes to grow quickly and revive Mrs Norris and Colin Creevey.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 11 (The Duelling Club)*</sup></sub>